# Facebook API JavaScript returning gender

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Basically what I need is to return the gender of each friend who is in the feed

The following does not work:

[image]

Comment: i don´t think it is possible to get the gender of users who are not authorized in your app

Answer (score 0):

`gender` is covered by `public_profile` permission – so you need to get that from every individual user first, before you can access it.

Without those friends becoming users of your app and granting it permission to access their basic profile information, you won’t be able to get this field.

---

Plus, the gender field will only return a value, if the user has chosen one of the “traditional” settings, male or female. If they entered their own custom value (which Facebook made possible a while ago), then the `gender` field will just return an empty string.